# Patch wall stud hole to screw in shelf for heavy loads

Tags: wood, studs, patch, shelf

I screwed a shelf bracket into a wall stud (behind sheet rock), but the screw kept on spinning. So I thought to insert a toggle bolt anchor to help hold up to 100 lbs of weight on the shelf. But when I drilled a hole large enough to accommodate the toggle bolt anchor, I saw a hint of light brown behind the sheet rock, which makes me wonder if there is indeed a wood stud behind the sheet rock at that point. My question is 1) why wouldn't the screw have taken to the stud in the first place, and 2) now that there is a large enough hole in the stud (large enough that I can't use a screw to fasten a bracket any more), how can I fill in the hole so it's sturdy enough to place another screw that will allow the shelf bracket to hold up to 100 lbs of weight?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely reason is you just missed the edge or just caught the edge of the stud.  Something most of us have done.

A stud is only 1.5 inches wide and if drywall is on it you are screwing blind.

Moving the screw 1/2 to 3/4 inch over should hit the stud right in the centre or open space.

Drywall hole can usually be filled with drywall mud.  Behind a shelf bracket even caulking would do.  You want the wood stud to hold the screw.  The bracket should cover imperfections in the wall.

I would never trust drywall alone to hold heavy weight or expensive items.  Always use studs or place plywood/wood planks(1x4s) across studs to hold screws.